# Can VSCode extensions be written in ReasonML?

Tags: visual-studio-code, reason

I would like to learn ReasonML for purposes of writing VSCode extensions. The tutorials on writing VSCode extensions all mention using TypeScript or JS, but as Reason is able to compile down to JS, would this work? If so, is there documentation on this topic? I have googled around but cannot find documentation regarding writing VScode Extensions with Reason.

Comment: See https://github.com/glennsl/reasonable-vscode-starter. It's pretty out-of-date on the Reason side of things, but should give you a pretty good idea of how to do it.

Comment: Also some more up-to-date bindings here: https://github.com/banacorn/bs-vscode